# document.getElementById returning element in firefox but not chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, dom, google-chrome

I am trying to dynamically load a coverflow type object (think itunes coverflow but less fancy) on a button click after the webpage has already loaded.  I am dynamically creating a list of images to feed to the javascript for the coverflow that then loads them and does it's magic to make it look pretty.  The problem is that in firefox the code is working, but in chrome and ie (surprise surprise) the javascript is throwing an error and the page is going blank due to the error throw below.  The problem is in this block of code that is trying to capture the dom element by id

```
if (typeof(this.Container) == 'string') { // no node
    var container = document.getElementById(this.Container);
    if (container) {
        this.Container = container;
    } else {
        throw ('ContentFlow ERROR: No element with id \''+this.Container+'\' found!');
        return;
    }
}
```

Pretty much in chrome the dome element is not captured by the code up above when it is definitely available in the page.  I even typed out `document.getElementById("container_name");` in the console of chrome and it returned the element so I am clueless as to whey it won't work in the file.

Any suggestions would be appreaciated

Thanks

EDIT:

here is the onpage html that is trying to be filled

```
<div id="contentFlow" class="cool_ui ContentFlow">
    <p id="coverflow_school_name"></p>
    <div class="loadIndicator"><div class="indicator"></div></div>
    <div class="flow" style="height:240px;"></div>
    <div class="scrollbar">
        <div class="slider"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ANSWERED:

Wow, ok.  I figured it out.  The problem was the way some resources were being dynamically loaded before the call to that piece of code.  The resource loading was causing the page to go blank, thus making var container = document.getElementById(this.Container); return null hence the exception being thrown.  Weird part was firefox could handle the resource loading, but chrome could not.

Thanks for the help

Comment: `typeof` is an operator, not a function, lose the parentheses

Comment: Can you post the HTML that goes along with this or reproduce it in a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com)?

Comment: I think we may need a complete example. Code should work but maybe you have some kind of race condition about whether the element has been loaded yet at the time the function fires, or something.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not use jquery?

```
 $('#container_name')
```

UPDATE: on second reading, is this the name or the Id of the element?

If it is name thenn use

```
$('[name="container_name"]')
```

Comment: tried that.  logged the returned object in chrom and it came back as an empty array [] while in firefox it had the whole element

Comment: I was going to disagree with this, but then I realized that the question is tagged with jquery... are you using jquery @user?

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you can just say

```
if($(this.Container).length){
    //Code goes here
}
else
{
    throw ('ContentFlow ERROR: No element with id \''+this.Container+'\' found!');
    return;
}
```

Comment: that's essentially the same thing as just capturing the container with jquery and then checking if it exists.  The problem is something within the browser i believe, since it works in firefox but not chrome

Comment: You have mentioned in the question that document.getElementById("container_name") returns element in chrome console then it should work fine. Did you trying using JQuery library?

Comment: yup, tried jquery.  the object captured in the code with jquery is just empty in chrome and filled in firefox

Comment: `$('#x')` is only going to do the same as `document.getElementById('x')`. jQuery is not some kind of magical fix. In any case `$(this.Container)` is wrong, it's missing the `#` to get an ID, and if there are out-of-band characters like `.` in the ID it would fail. You don't get anything by wrapping a simple byId query in a more complex selector query.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code in Chrome 12.0.742.112 and it seems to work fine. Here is a link: http://jsfiddle.net/eemYg/.

I presume another thing is causing the problem, for example `this.Container`. You should check it's value (in Chrome) and see if it has a different value than the one in Firefox.